# Unable to run code in react yahoo finance 2 package

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, yahoo-finance

I'm building a react(`tsx`) app using Vite. My app gets stock-related info from Yahoo using [yahoo-finance2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yahoo-finance2) package.

When I'm running as a standalone js file, it is working as expected. But, when I use the same in react, I get an error as **Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined**. Here is my code.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import yahooFinance from "yahoo-finance2";

function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getQuote = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const response = await yahooFinance.quote("TSLA");
        console.log(response);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    getQuote();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="flex w-full h-screen justify-center items-center">
      <div className="text-lg">{isLoading ? `Loading...` : `Hello world!`}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Can someone please let me know where I'm going wrong? [Here](https://github.com/sunnykeerthi/stocks-app) is my repo, if helpful.
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the same thing in React/Vite. I even commented out the call to yahooFinance, so got the message by simply importing yahooFinance from 'yahoo-finance2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly an answer, but after looking at many options I believe I found a much better source for the information you need. The API is very well documented. Here is the code I use to access quotes from alphavantage.co.

```
async function updateExchangeRate() {
    fetch('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=demo')
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
        })
}
```

It was trivial to instantaneously get an apikey (to replace "demo" in the url above).